# LEFT JOIN LATERAL conditions and JSONB

Tags: postgresql, join, json

I have a `JSONB` column (`jb_column`) that may have a key (let's call it `schrodinger`) or not. When the `schrodinger` key is present, it's value can either be `null::JSONB` or a regular `JSONB` object.

First, a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    jb_column JSONB
);
```

The structure I'm trying to extract from the `schrodinger` column:

```sql
CREATE TYPE schrodinger AS
(
    foo NUMERIC,
    bar TEXT
);
```

And this was my initial approach:

```sql
SELECT mt.id, s.*
FROM my_table mt
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_record(null::schrodinger, mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') s
```

But this resulted in the annoying error below:

`[22023] ERROR: cannot call populate_composite on a scalar`

After a couple of hours trying to debug it, I nailed it down to the `null::JSONP` values of the `schrodinger` key. So, my next attempt was to add some criteria to the JOIN, so that PG could ignore those...

```sql
SELECT mt.id, s.*
FROM my_table mt
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_record(null::schrodinger, mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') s
          ON jsonb_typeof(mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') != 'null'
```

I'd expect this condition to skip the JOIN when both the key is not present as well as when it's there, but `null::JSONP`... Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working, since I still get the same error.

I also tried `jsonb_typeof(mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') = 'object'`, to no avail.

Thoughts?

*edit*: online example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66c90482a33aa458c6a90e1bbaa1ec9d

Comment: Could you use a CTE to omit the records out that have a `null` value for schrodinger? otherwise the other thing you may try could be a case statement on your join (not sure if that would work, but might get you going in the right direction) https://clarkdave.net/2015/03/navigating-null-safety-with-json-and-postgresql/

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66c90482a33aa458c6a90e1bbaa1ec9d

Answer (score 1):

`jsonb_populate_record` can't be used like a table as it only returns a scalar values.

I think you want

```
select id, (jsonb_populate_record(null::schrodinger, mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger')).* 
from my_table mt
```

If the json value doesn't contain the key `schrodinger` then this will automatically return `null`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=da41cb5dfcb0c1bd2b801ade10596e3b)

Comment: I humbly disagree with you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=04adabf919fe45c9c791372b54a82a28

Comment: Well the join makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: Going that way, would it be possible to, let's say, alias `schrodinger.foo` and `schrodinger.bar` as `s_foo` and `s_bar`?

Comment: @tavlima: why not simply leave out the type completely? `(jb_column #>> '{schrodinger,foo}')::numeric as s_foo`?

Comment: Because the post was just a trivial example to explain the problem. The actual type has around 15 fields and that level of verbosity would soon render the query unmaintanable (I’m actually building a view on top of that jsonb data), while possibly reducing the performance (if I got PG docs correctly).

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, the problem is when `jsonb_typeof(mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') = 'null'`, there is nothing for jsonb_populate_record() to work on.

The real problem is with the (LEFT) OUTER JOIN. Roughly speaking, a OUTER JOIN keeps the rows where the join condition is NULL, which is the case for the jsonb operator `->` according to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html):

> Note
>
> The field/element/path extraction operators return NULL, rather than
> failing, if the JSON input does not have the right structure to match
> the request; for example if no such key or array element exists.

For example, `SELECT '{}'::jsonb-> 'a' IS NULL;` is true under PostgreSQL 15.

Then, I think the NULL value triggers the error for forcing `jsonb_populate_record` to work on null.

To avoid the issue, you can use an INNER JOIN instead of the OUTER JOIN ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hot3SSik)):

```
SELECT mt.id, s.*
FROM my_table mt
INNER JOIN jsonb_populate_record(null::schrodinger, mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') s
  ON jsonb_typeof(mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') != 'null';
```

Alternatively, using WHERE ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A7XHZD7t)) seems to solve the problem too:

```
SELECT mt.id, s.*
FROM my_table mt
LEFT JOIN jsonb_populate_record(null::schrodinger, mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') s
  ON true
WHERE jsonb_typeof(mt.jb_column -> 'schrodinger') != 'null';
```